# Matplotlib, plotting multiple individual hline on barplot from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a simple pandas dataframe and plot like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np

test_df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(100, size=(10,2)), columns = ['COL_A', 'COL_B'], index=list('abcdefghij'))
test_df_1.plot(kind='bar')
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

I then have another dataframe:

```
test_df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(100, size=(10,2)), columns = ['COL_A', 'COL_B'], index=list('abcdefghij'))
```

Which is the same dimensions as my first dataframe. I wish to plot over the top as simple horizontal lines, like the following mock up:

[image]

How do I achieve this? I know of `axhline` but I don't know how I can apply it in this instance to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think a better method, but you can get the information of the bars from `ax.patches`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np

test_df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(100, size=(10,2)), columns = ['COL_A', 'COL_B'], index=list('abcdefghij'))
ax = test_df_1.plot(kind='bar')
test_df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(100, size=(10,2)), columns = ['COL_A', 'COL_B'], index=list('abcdefghij'))

x = np.array([r.get_x() for r in ax.patches])
w = np.array([r.get_width() for r in ax.patches])

ax.hlines(test_df_2.values.T.ravel(), x, x + w, color="red", lw=2)
```

Here is the output:

[image]